# changing activity from view pager

Tags: java, android, android-fragments, android-recyclerview, runnable

Hope you all are doing well and safe.

I am in need of your genius help, explaining my problem below:

I have 2 activities, one activity is having bottom navigation of five fragments, each fragments have viewpager consist on atleast 2 fragments and every fragments have recyclerview.Bottom navigation fragments open in FragmentContainerView each recycler view is updating list data on every 2 seconds using notifyDataSetChanged. On the other hand, 2nd activity consists of viewpager consisting of 3 fragments and a bottom sheet, its bottom sheet activty it self have runables and handler updating values.

my issue is when I try to open 2nd activity from the first activity it takes too long to open. please help, If you guys can.. I'll be very thankful to you all............

Answer (score 0):

An activity takes too long to open when too much code is in the `onCreate()` method. This also happens when you are running a lot of code in `onStart().` All the code that you write, by default, runs on the same thread. This makes the app too long to load. Try to display toast on the second activity immediately after the `setContentView().` You will see the toast shown, but the activity opens later. This is only due to so much code. You can solve the problem by putting the code in a new `Thread`. Something like this:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
thread.start();

Runnable runnable = new Runnable(){
    public void run() {   
       //enter most(not all) of your code here
    }
};
```

Comment: sounds helpfull, might work. Please stay active I might need more help.

Comment: I tried, toast is showing after activity open. duration is same.

Comment: pleas share your entire second activity code

Comment: unable to share here, too long, can you help me through anyother way? like anydesk or other? I am facing few issues, your help can save me.

Comment: paste it [here](https://wtools.io/paste-code)

Comment: https://wtools.io/paste-code/bAu1

Comment: I see that you have this line:`UpdateSingleFeed updateSingleFeed = new UpdateSingleFeed();`. Don't initialize it in the class. Initialize it in the `onCreate` method instead

Comment: where should I initialise it?

Comment: as mentioned. In the `onCreate` method

Comment: nothing happened even after comment the whole class.

Comment: The only thing I figure out is that too much code is blocking the main thread of that activity. Only try decreasing the code or adding some of the code in a new Thread.

Comment: holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Logs.market = null;
                Logs.scrip = null;
                Intent intent = new Intent(context.getApplicationContext(), SymbolDetailsActivity.class);
                intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
                Toast.makeText(context, "onCreate setOnClickListener", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            context.startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

Comment: even the toast are poping up late.

Comment: yes indeed. that is expected. There is too much code. Add it in a new thread. Should i give the code?

Comment: yes please share your code.

Comment: ok. wait 2 mins

Comment: how to stop and resume thread on  activity on Pause and onResume method?